# Livewire 3 rendering / refresh works only in dev mode

Tags: rendering, laravel-livewire

I have an issue with proper working livewire in laravel project, page is loading well but is not rendering livewire functions (like refresh button or increment function as presentet on official livewire page documentation).

It works fully only in development mode (using php artisan serve command), but connecting by standard IP address is stopping to render / live feresh the content.

Please help.

In case livewire 2.3 I manage it adding to config/livewire.php
'asset_url'  => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'), where APP_URL is my ip address of serwer
insted of:
'asset_url' => null,
but in case of livewire 3 it does not work (default config file not include "'asset_url' => null,").

In web browser dev panel is not showing any issue.

I am using:
PHP: 8.2.4
Laravel: 10.30.1
XAMP: 3.3
Windows: 11